# Run only if "if " statement is true.!

Tags: python, fits

So I've a question, Like I'm reading the fits file and then i'm using the information from the header of the fits to define the other files which are related to the original fits file. But for some of the fits file, the other files (blaze_file, bis_file, ccf_table) are not available. And because of that my code gives the pretty obvious error that  **No Such file or directory**. [image]

```
import pandas as pd
import sys, os
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from astropy.io import fits

PATH = os.path.join("home", "Desktop", "2d_spectra")
for filename in os.listdir(PATH):
  if filename.endswith("_e2ds_A.fits"):
     e2ds_hdu = fits.open(filename)
     e2ds_header = e2ds_hdu[0].header

     date = e2ds_header['DATE-OBS']
     date2 = date = date[0:19]

     blaze_file = e2ds_header['HIERARCH ESO DRS BLAZE FILE']
     bis_file = glob('HARPS.' + date2 + '*_bis_G2_A.fits')
     ccf_table = glob('HARPS.' + date2 + '*_ccf_G2_A.tbl')
     if not all(file in os.listdir(PATH) for file in [blaze_file,bis_file,ccf_table]):
       continue
```

So  what i want to do is like, i want to make my code run only if all the files are available otherwise don't. But the problem is that, i'm defining the other files as variable inside the for loop as i'm using the header information. So how can i define them before the for loop???? and then use something like

So can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: Split the code in two different loops, first check that all files are here then do your computation. If the other files names are defined inside some files you'll have no other choice, unless I don't understand the question.

Comment: Are you sure the error comes the dependant files not being available ? The code snippet you posted only open the fits files, and will break if you're running the code from anywhere else than /home/Desktop/2d_spectra, cf glglgl's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The filenames returned by `os.listdir()` are always relative to the path given there.

In order to be used, they have to be joined with this path.

Example:

```
PATH = os.path.join("home", "Desktop", "2d_spectra")

for filename in os.listdir(PATH):
  if filename.endswith("_e2ds_A.fits"):
     filepath = os.path.join(PATH, filename)
     e2ds_hdu = fits.open(filepath)
     …
```

Let the filenames be `['a', 'b', 'a_ed2ds_A.fits', 'b_ed2ds_A.fits']`. The code now excludes the two first names and then prepends the file path to the remaining two.

`a_ed2ds_A.fits` becomes `/home/Desktop/2d_spectra/a_ed2ds_A.fits` and
`b_ed2ds_A.fits` becomes `/home/Desktop/2d_spectra/b_ed2ds_A.fits`.

Now they can be accessed from everywhere, not just from the given file path.

---

I should become accustomed to reading a question in full before trying to answer it.

The problem I mentionned *is* a problem if you don't start the script from any path outside the said directory. Nevertheless, applying it will make your code much more consistent.

Your real problem, however, lies somewhere else: you examine a file and then, after checking its contents, want to read files whose names depend on informations from that first file.

There are several ways to accomplish your goal:

1. Just extend your loop with the proper tests.

   Pseudo code:

   ```
   for file in files:
       if file.endswith("fits"):
           open file
           read date from header
           create file names depending on date
           if all files exist:
               proceed
   ```

   or

   ```
   for file in files:
       if file.endswith("fits"):
           open file
           read date from header
           create file names depending on date
           if not all files exist:
               continue # actual keyword, no pseudo code!
           proceed
   ```
2. Put some functionality into functions (variation of 1.)
3. Create a loop in a generator function which yields the "interesting information" of one fits file (or alternatively nothing) and have another loop run over them to actually work with the data.

If I am still missing some points or am not detailled enough, please let me know.

Comment: while this is an important notice and the OP should indeed add this fix to his code, it's not actually an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @astroluv the informations in your questions are not enough to tell if it's the issue or not (cf my comment to your question). But you do want to apply this fix to your code anyway - relying on the current working directory to be what you expect is doomed to fail one day or another.

Comment: Hey i have edited my question, that's what you wanted me to do? right? But sill it's giving me some error. All the information is there in the header but still it's giving the error. What i'm missing?? @glglgl

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to read the fits file to know the other dependant files names, there's no way you can avoid reading the fit file first. The only thing you can do is test for the dependant files existance before trying to read them and skip the rest of the loop (using `continue`) if not.

Comment: Ok, i'll try that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this line

```
e2ds_hdu = fits.open(filename)
```

And replace with

```
e2ds_hdu = fits.open(os.path.join(PATH, filename))
```

Comment: In how far does your answer add information which mine doesn't?

Comment: It's no the comparison between any. it's just a simple answer to indicating the error and quick solution